# error in importing angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
    First Name : <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"> <br>
    Last Name : <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"> <br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
  </div>

  <script>
  var person={
    firstName = "john" ,
    lastName = "Doe"
  };

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCntrl', function($scope){
    $scope.firstName = person.firstName;
    $scope.lastName = person.lastName
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but I got this when run

> angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.4%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A425%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A26%3A270%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A25%3A299)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A26%3A44%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A117%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A495)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A476)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A44)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A373)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Sc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179)
>   at angular.js:38
>   at angular.js:4920
>   at q (angular.js:403)
>   at g (angular.js:4880)
>   at eb (angular.js:4802)
>   at c (angular.js:1914)
>   at Sc (angular.js:1935)
>   at ue (angular.js:1820)
>   at angular.js:33367
>   at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3431)

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare person object properly with correct syntax within the scope of angular. So move your object inside the controller.

```js
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCntrl', function($scope) {
      var person = {
          firstName: "john",
          lastName: "Doe"
      };
      $scope.firstName = person.firstName;
      $scope.lastName = person.lastName
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl"> First Name :
        <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
        <br> Last Name :
        <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
        <br>
        <br> Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}} </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what was the problem ?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Your object declaration was not correct and it is better to use person as an object in the scope of angularjs application rather than declaring it global.

Comment: Even if you declare the variable globally, it will work though it is not recommended